# Laser power inside a vapour cell

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, quantum-optics, spectroscopy

I have a laser beam whose power I measured to be x $\text{mW/cm}^2$. Furthermore, I measured the beam profile of the laser beam and therefore can estimate its intensity. I shine this laser through a vapour cell filled with Rubidium atoms and after it passed the vapour cell let it reflect by a mirror and pass through the vapour cell again (perfectly collinear). Will the laser power/intensity inside my vapour cell be doubled since there are now effectively two laser beams? Or will there just form a standing wave and the power/intensity are unaffected?

This is relevant since, e.g., the scattering rate in Doppler cooling requires knowledge of the laser intensity "as perceived by the atoms".

Answer (score 0):

In short it depends on the coherence of the laser and the path length. Its basically a michleson interferometer.

Comment: And how would I be able to determine if this is the case in my setup or not? The total path length from laser source/Faraday isolator to aforementioned mirror are several meters. I don't have any particular knowledge regarding the coherence of my laser.

Comment: You probably will be on and it will just be double the irradiance. You could measure it with a beam pick off and a power meter.